# npm cannot install from registry.npmjs.org

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl, npm, proxy

Ok, I'm getting this response when i do:

```
npm search rollup

npm ERR! pna.nextTick is not a function
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=503
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

I've set the npm http and http-proxy settings, and i have the http & http_proxy settings set as well. I've used curl with explicit proxy set and servername as well. With curl I get my squid returning a "some aspect of the requested url is incorrect". Curl has it's capath set to use the mozilla set of cafiles. And using n, which uses curl, n is able to download and install the new version of node.

On my perimeter router, I'm able to use w3m and curl to at least retrieve some kind of output from the server. w3m serves the most information, which is a long list of minified json. curl retrieves a line of json.

Seeing as how this is a few weeks after that eslint password stealing bug, how should one proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Right, so it appears that it is a matter of having auto installing non compatible versions of node using n.

To resolve the issue:

```
n lts
npm install -g npm
n stable
```

Presumably the lts version installs an npm that can be upgraded to support node 10.8.0. So upgrading node to stable means you get a working npm. Still this seems like a better solution than some of the others that call for running npm without ssl ( and probably doesn't work ).